# Achieving multiple locks in clojure

Tags: multithreading, clojure, locking

I'm new to Clojure and am writing a web application. It includes a function `fn` performed on user `user-id` which includes several steps of reading and writing to the database and file system. These steps cannot be performed simultaneously by multiple threads (will cause database and file system inconsistencies) and I don't believe they can be performed using a database transaction. However, they are specific to one user and thus can be performed simultaneously for different users.

Thus, if a http request is made to perform `fn` for a specific `user-id` I need to make sure that it is completed before any http requests can perform `fn` for this `user-id`

I've come up with a solution that seems to work in the REPL but have not tried it in the web server yet. However, being unexperienced with Clojure and threaded programming I'm not sure whether this is a good or safe way to solve the problem. The following code has been developed by trial-and-error and uses the `locking` function - which seems to go against the "no locks" philosophy of Clojure.

```
(ns locking.core)    

;;; Check if var representing lock exists in namespace
;;; If not, create it. Creating a new var if one already
;;; exists seems to break the locking.
(defn create-lock-var
  [var-name value]
  (let [var-sym (symbol var-name)]
    (do
      (when (nil? (ns-resolve 'locking.core var-sym))
        (intern 'locking.core var-sym value))
      ;; Return lock var
      (ns-resolve 'locking.core var-sym))))

;;; Takes an id which represents the lock and the function
;;; which may only run in one thread at a time for a specific id
(defn lock-function
  [lock-id transaction]
  (let [lock (create-lock-var (str "lock-id-" lock-id) lock-id)]
    (future
      (locking lock
        (transaction)))))

;;; A function to test the locking
(defn test-transaction
  [transaction-count sleep]
  (dotimes [x transaction-count]
    (Thread/sleep sleep)
    (println "performing operation" x)))
```

If I open three windows in REPL and execute these functions, it works

```
repl1 > (lock-function 1 #(test-transaction 10 1000)) ; executes immediately
repl2 > (lock-function 1 #(test-transaction 10 1000)) ; waits for repl1 to finish
repl2 > (lock-function 2 #(test-transaction 10 1000)) ; executes immediately because id=2
```

Is this reliable? Are there better ways to solve the problem?

**UPDATE**

As pointed out, the creation of the lock variable is not atomic. I've re-written the `lock-function` function and it seems to work (no need for `create-lock-var`)

```
(def locks (atom {}))

(defn lock-transaction
  [lock-id transaction]
  (let [lock-key (keyword (str "lock-id-" lock-id))]
    (do
      (compare-and-set! locks (dissoc @locks lock-key) (assoc @locks lock-key lock-id))
      (future
        (locking (lock-key @locks)
          (transaction))))))
```

*Note*: Renamed the function to `lock-transaction`, seems more appropriate.

Comment: `create-lock-var` has a race condition, because the check for the var and the creation of the var are not a single atomic operation

Comment: Yes, I had that feeling as well - thank you for confirming! How can I make that specific operation atomic?

Comment: Do you plan to deploy multiple instances of your application behind of load balancer for high availability? If you do then you need to rethink your approach to use distributed locking or change your architecture.

Comment: Thank you for your question and raising an important point! Initially we will not have that much traffic that we need load balancing or multiple instances. The need for locking is actually a consequence of an old PHP and ORM architecture on which we are building a Clojure application. When all PHP code has been replaced the database will be restructured and hopefully the need for locks within instances will disappear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use N vars in a namespace, use an atom wrapped around 1 hash-map mapping N symbols to N locks. This fixes your current race condition, avoids creating a bunch of silly vars, and is easier to write anyway.

Comment: Thank you! That was very helpful. I have rewritten the `lock-function`  function and updated my question with the new function. I hope/think that it is atomic now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're making a web app, I have to warn you: even if you do manage to get in-process locking right (which is not easy in itself), it will be for nothing as soon as you deploy your web server on more than one machine (which is almost mandatory if you want your app to be highly-available).

So basically, if you want to use locking, you'd better use *distributed* locking. From this point on, this discussion is not Clojure-specific, since Clojure's concurrency tools won't be especially helpful here.

**For distributed locking**, you could use something like [Zookeeper](https://zookeeper.apache.org/). If you don't want to set up a whole Zookeeper cluster just for this, maybe you can compromise by using a [Redis](http://redis.io/) database (the [Carmine](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/carmine) library gives you distributed locks out of the box), although [last time I heard](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html) Redis locking is not 100% reliable.

Now, it seems to me locking is not especially a requirement, and is not the best approach, especially if you're striving for idiomatic Clojure. **How about using a queue** instead ? Some popular JVM message brokers (such as HornetQ and ActiveMQ) give you [*Message Grouping*](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.3.0.beta1/docs/user-manual/html/message-grouping.html), which guarantees that messages of the same group-id will be processed (serially) by the same consumer. All you have to do is have some threads listen to the right queue and set the user-id as the group id for your messages.

HACK: If you don't want to set up a distributed message broker, maybe you could get around by enabling sticky sessions on you load balancer, and using such a message broker in-VM.

By the way, don't name your function `fn` :).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! The many problems with locking that you pointed out actually made me restructure the old database that we are working against. Now the need for locks has been removed.